# Fechar modal quando clicar no botão

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Ola, eu tenho essa seguinte modal, sempre que eu clico no botao "Recusou venda" ele abre, porem eu queria fechar essa mesma modal toda vez que ele clicasse no botao "Enviar", que no caso e meu submit, como eu faço isso?

```
<div class="chat-form">
    <button data-toggle="modal" href="#redModal"  class="btn btn-block red">Recusou venda</button>
  </div>
<!-- Modal info adicionais -->
<div id="redModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"> <i class="fa fa-checker"></i> Recusou</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
              <h3 class="blue-hoki">Recusou a venda</h3>
              <br>
              <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="recusouVenda(rForm.value)">
                  <div class="row form-modal">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label>Comentario:
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <textarea [value]="valorInput" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="comentario"></textarea>
                              </div>
                          </label>
                      </div>

                      <br><br><br>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn red">Enviar</button>
                  </div>

              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem que postar seu código completo, com o JavaScript também. Mas seria dar um preventDefault no submit do botão e colocar a função de fechar dentro do evento de submit.

Comment: eu nao uso o javascript em nada da modal

Comment: Quando clica em "enviar" a página não é submetida (recarregada)?

Comment: O projeto e feito em angular, então nao e recarregado nada

Comment: Nao consegui entender sua pergunta, me parece meio vaga, eu testei seu codigo e quando eu clico em enviar ele fecha normalmente.

Comment: Não tem uma maneira que faça ele fechar por javascript ou algo do tipo nao?

Comment: Mas se está utilizando Angular, não é só ir no arquivo Typescript do componente que criou o modal e instanciar o método **close()**??

Comment: isso nao e outro component, e no mesmo

Comment: Indiferente de onde criou o modal, poderia colocar seu **ts** também na pergunta.

Comment: mas nao tem literalmente nada no meu ts, isso funciona por si so, unica e exclusivamente no html

Comment: Bom, não estou entendendo muito bem como você fez, mas, não bastaria apenas adicionar isto **data-dismiss="modal"** no botão enviar??

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap está usando? Acredito qu fazendo o que o @LeAndrade falou da certo!

Answer (score 3):

> A propósito, você colocou duas class `.btn` no botão de submit:
>
> ```
> <button type="submit" class="btn btn red">Enviar</button>
> ```

Para fechar o modal de forma manual você pode usar o método:

```
$("#redModal").modal('hide');
```

Para isso você cria um evento de click no botão submit:

```
$(":submit").on("click", function(){
    $("#redModal").modal('hide');
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(":submit").on("click", function(){
    $("#redModal").modal('hide');
});

// as linhas abaixo são apenas para não submeter o form. Não copie

$("form").submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="chat-form">
    <button data-toggle="modal" href="#redModal"  class="btn btn-block red">Recusou venda</button>
  </div>
<!-- Modal info adicionais -->
<div id="redModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title"> <i class="fa fa-checker"></i> Recusou</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body text-center">
              <h3 class="blue-hoki">Recusou a venda</h3>
              <br>
              <form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="recusouVenda(rForm.value)">
                  <div class="row form-modal">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label>Comentario:
                              <div class="input-group">
                                  <textarea [value]="valorInput" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="comentario"></textarea>
                              </div>
                          </label>
                      </div>

                      <br><br><br>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn red">Enviar</button>
                  </div>

              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```