# Como fechar Modal do bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, asp-net-core

Antes de qualquer coisa adianto que li outros posts...
[Fechar modal quando clicar no botão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352357/fechar-modal-quando-clicar-no-bot%C3%A3o)

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema no ASP NET Core e utilizando um modal do bootstrap para fazer um login.
Enviei os dados para a controller pelo javascript e validei...

```
$("#btn-entrar").click(function () {

        var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
        var senha = $("#inputPassword").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Logar",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                email: email, senha: senha
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.hasOwnProperty("erro")) {
                    var contaUsuario = document.getElementById('usuLogado');
                    contaUsuario.style.display = "inline";
                    $('#modalLogin').modal('hide');
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.erro);
                }
            }

        })

    })
```

O problema é que o modal.('hide') nao está funcionando 100%...explicando...
Quando o modal abre ele sobrepõe a pagina principal e esmaece(deixa cinza, sem foco) a pagina atras, correto? O meu modal.('hide') fecha sim o modal, mas nao restaura o foco na pagina...eu nao consigo clicar em nada.

Comment: Joelend, é que tem outra div abrindo pra "desfocar" (dar efeito de escuro) ao site, você vai precisar verificar no seu inspecionar elemento qual div é essa pra poder fechar, ou se quiser, você pode enviar aqui na pergunta o código completo do modal pra que eu possa ajudar xD

Comment: Sim...acabei de ver, tem mesmo uma div...e oque eu faço com ela?

Comment: Tem como colocar o exemplo do seu código aqui, do modal?

Comment: a div é essa: <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>

Answer (score 1):

O fundo escuro que fica por trás da modal e por cima do conteúdo geral da página é uma div com classe `.modal-backdrop` que é gerada quando se abre a modal. Quando a modal é fechada, essa div é simplesmente removida do DOM (da página).

O normal é que isso ocorra naturalmente, ou seja: fecha a modal, o backdrop some. Mas você pode remover ele manualmente com o seguinte código:

```
$(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

Não é para esconder ele não, é pra **remover** mesmo, porque, como dito, ao abrir a modal novamente, um novo backdrop é gerado.

Answer (score -2):

Não sei se pode ajuda-los.

minha solução para o **bootstrap 5.3**, foi a seguinte;

na div, adicionei a class apenas o atributo (**pe-none**). com isso o comportamento do me modal foi como esperado, "**Fechar apenas ao click do botão**".

parte do código: ***<div class="modal fade pe-none"***

bem simples, não?